# Using WITH (NOLOCK) and Transactions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Say I have a simple query such as

```
Select * From MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)
```

And, at the same time this query is executing, another user is inserting 100 rows into this table within the context of a transaction.

Is it theoretically possible that the Select statement, because it's using NOLOCK, could read a subset of the 100 rows being inserted into the table, before the transaction is committed or rolled back? If I understand NOLOCK correctly, this seems like it could be a possibility, but wanted to verify.

SQL Server 2012

Comment: Actually I think you could read all 100 not just a subset prior to the  commit or rollback.

Comment: @Blam Don't agree. Please see my updated answer which proves otherwise.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I think you may be at cross purposes. I interpreted Blam's remark as saying that *as well as* reading a (proper) subset of the affected rows you could also read the whole set of rows before they are committed/rolled back.

Comment: @Martin I read it as "all 100 rows from the insert, or nothing" - after all, the question talks about another transaction inserting 100 rows. I see your interpretation too, reading it again now with your comment in mind, but it's far from clear that's what was meant.

Comment: Yes only Blam can confirm for sure! @Randy BTW as well as reading a subset of uncommitted rows you can even read a partially updated column in [some circumstances](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/9827/3690)

Comment: "All 100 not just a subset" needs clarification?  If meant all or nothing I would have said "All 100 not a subset".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Certainly, you can read a subset or all of the uncommitted data that is affected between the beginning of a transaction and the commit or rollback. That's kind of the point of `NOLOCK` - to allow you to read data that is not committed so that you don't have to wait for writers, and to avoid placing most locks so that writers don't have to wait for you.

**Proof #1**

This is very easy to prove. In one window, create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.what(id INT);
```

In a second window, run this query:

```
DECLARE @id INT;

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
 SELECT @id = id FROM dbo.what WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE id = 2;

 IF @id = 2
 BEGIN
   PRINT @id;
   BREAK;
 END
END
```

Now go back to the first window, and start an intentionally long-running transaction, but roll it back:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
GO

INSERT dbo.what SELECT 2;
GO 10000

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

As soon as you start this in the first window, the query in the second window will halt and will spit out the uncommitted value that was read.

**Proof #2**

This is primarily to contest @Blam's comment above, which I don't agree with:

> Actually I think you could read all 100 not just a subset prior to the commit or rollback.

You most certainly can read subsets of rows affected by a transaction. Try the following, similar example, this time inserting sets of 100 into the table, 1000 times, and retrieving the count in the query using `(NOLOCK)`. Window #1 (if you haven't already tested proof #1 above):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.what(id INT);
```

Window #2:

```
DECLARE @c INT;

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
 SELECT @c = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.what WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE id = 2;

 IF @c > 0
   PRINT @c;

 IF @c > 10000
   BREAK;
END
```

Back in Window #1:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
GO

INSERT dbo.what SELECT TOP (100) 2 FROM sys.all_objects;
GO 1000

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

Window #2 will spin until you start the transaction. As soon as you do, you'll start seeing counts trickle in. But they won't be in multiples of 100 (never mind 100,000, the all or nothing claim @Blam seems to be making). Here are my abridged results:

```
1
10
12
14
17
19
23
25
29
...
85
87
91
95
98
100
100
...
9700
9700
9763
9800
9838
9900
9936
10000
10000
10000
10080
```

The `NOLOCK` query clearly does not wait for any single statement to finish before reading the data, never mind the entire transaction. So you could get the data in any state of flux, regardless of how many rows each statement affects and regardless of how many statements are in the entire transaction.

**Other side effects**

There are also cases where `NOLOCK` can [skip rows, or read the same row twice](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/beware-nolock-hint), depending on the type of scan and when another transaction is generating page splits. Essentially what happens is as the `(NOLOCK)` query is reading data, other writes can actually move data to a different location - because they can - either moving a row you've already read to a point further ahead in your scan, or moving a row you haven't read yet to a point earlier in your scan.

**Advice**

In general, it's bad news, and you should consider `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` instead - it has the same benefit of allowing readers to not block writers and vice-versa, but gives you a consistent view of the data at a point in time, ignoring all subsequent data modifications (this has an impact to tempdb though, so be sure to test it). [Very thorough information here](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/).

Answer (score 4):

As Aaron has elegantly explained, yes you will read the dirty uncommitted data.  But if you want to avoid reading the dirty data, and are not yet ready to start using optimistic locking, you can try using the [READPAST](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) table hint like below, though that has the effect that it will skip over any rows that are locked, so you won't see inserted and updated rows that haven't been committed yet.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable WITH (READPAST)
```

Note that this table hint requires that the database be operating in either READ COMMITTED (the default) or REPEATABLE READ isolation levels.